# Correct Join Syntax to connect just the rows from Table A that match with Table B

Tags: mysql, sql, join

**My Goal**

I'm trying to do a join on table A and table B.

I want to list out all the people who live at each street in table A. But I don't want to list *everyone* in table A, only the people who live at each street in table B.

**What I've tried**

- Inner Join on A and B : returns only the first person at each address
- Left Join : returns everyone
- Right Join : returns the two streets from B, first person at each address

**Table A**

```
Fred    123 Fake Street
Bob     456 Any Street
Alice   456 Any Street
Jenny   879 Spring Street
Cassie  879 Spring Street
Spinner 227 Nothing Street
Ranger  227 Nothing Street
Swifty  227 Nothing Street
Loggy   821 Victory Way
```

**Table B**

```
227 Nothing Street
456 Any Street
```

**Query Result (some type of join)**

```
Spinner 227 Nothing Street
Ranger  227 Nothing Street
Swifty  227 Nothing Street
Bob     456 Any Street
Alice   456 Any Street
```

Comment: Is table A one or two columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INNER JOIN` works fine:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b ON b.address = a.address
```

Output:

```
name    address
Bob     456 Any Street
Alice   456 Any Street
Spinner 227 Nothing Street
Ranger  227 Nothing Street
Swifty  227 Nothing Street
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=692d18af16a2b931be58f2eff56c97bc)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1 from b where b.address = a.address);
```

You can do the same thing with an `inner join`.  I have no idea what you mean by "Inner Join on A and B : returns only the first person at each address".  That is simply incorrect.